How to fill form using session data in filament 3?
I want if the session has data then the data from the session must be displayed otherwise it should display the details from the table in the edit page.
I have tried filling data using default() method. But table has value of certain field so it doesn't work in edit page because if it has no value then it will show value which is defined as default. So it works with create page but not with edit page.
I also tried with the afterStateUpdated() method but it didn't work.
Please let me know how I can manually fill the form data in the edit page?
